# Textmate - View in Skim stopped working after Skim update

Tags: pdftex, textmate

I think this error starts after updating skim to the latest version.

```
Document 'PDFfile.pdf' not open in application LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the 
application /private/var/folders/O9/O9WzNPBfEsCRnERR4J07f++++TI/-Tmp-/Skim 62 
Update/B121659D-D5E2-4EF3-A582-A94789DEE5D6/Skim.app with error -10810 for the file 
PDFfile.pdf. sh: /private/var/folders/O9/O9WzNPBfEsCRnERR4J07f++++TI/-Tmp-/Skim 62
 Update/B121659D-D5E2-4EF3-A582-A94789DEE5D6/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline: 
No such file or directory

error number 256 opening viewer
```

It seems the link to the Skim.app is wrong. The Application is installed at /Applications/Skim.app and the displayline file exists at the path under the app.

I have not created anything in my setup, which has worked great for some years.

How can I change the path to Skim?

Comment: I figured out by myself. If I deleted the tmp folder for the Skim 62 Update, the correct skim opened again. 

I also ran this command, to ensure that the open with path to Skim was correct

    `locate lsregister` -kill -r -all local,system, user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out by myself. 
If I deleted the tmp folder for the Skim 62 Update, the correct skim opened again. 
I also ran this command, to ensure that the open with path to Skim was correct locate `lsregister -kill -r -all local,system, user`

Comment: I just noticed another detail that can trigger this error.  If you have a `'` in your .tex files path name ie: `~/Documents/Bret\'s\ stuff/`  Removing the `'` from that directory name, or moving the tex file to a different path clears up the error.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to reinstall TM and Skim in the folder Applications, then verify the PATH with `$echo $PATH`.

I use TextMate Version 1.5.10 (1631) and Skim 1.3.13.

In Skim : [image]

In TextMate : advanced prefs [image]

In LaTeX Bundle Prefs : [image]

Now I use OS X 10..6.7 and all work fine with synchro etc.

Do you use the Bundle LaTeX original ? or LaTeX 2 ? and do you have change some scripts ?

Do you have update Python or Ruby ? LaTeX bundle use Python and LaTeX 2 uses Ruby !

Comment: I am using the standard Latex bundle, But the problem was the skim path where the update confused textmate. It works now, but I can only answer my on question after 24 hours :/

Comment: Perhaps you need to remove the old prefs of Skim. It's often the simplest solution. You can delete all the folders created by Skim, Skim and the prefs of Skim. Sometimes i need to download Skim manually; because the DL fails.